# to run script over several folders?

Tags: bash, shell

Currently I have a script that can run only in a single folder.

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in ls -1 *.jpg|sort -t . -n -k 3
do
  echo "compute ./scripName $file"
  ./scriptName $file
done
```

Question: I have a several folders containing `*.jpg` images. I need a script that can over all images of all folders.

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: Do you have a list of folders, or do you want it to scan the whole drive?

Comment: I would like to scan the whole parent folder.

Answer (score 0):

you can use a nested for loop,

```
for f in folder1 folder2 folder3; 
do
   cd $f
   for file in ls -1 *.jpg|sort -t . -n -k 3
   do
      echo "compute ./scripName $file"
      ./scriptName $file
   done  
done
```

***Please note that this is not a foolproof script and in this case folder1,folder2... have to be a full paths to make this script to work.**

Comment: Thanks! I m wondering if we can make it for N folders, where we can avoid user input. can we?

Comment: It depend who the folders are spread and if they have something in common (some search criteria).